# Deploying war to tomcat 8 using Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, web-deployment

I want to simply deploy the war file present on a jenkins slave on a remote tomcat.

I thought this plugin is useful https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

[image]

The console output is as follows:

```
Building remotely on temporary node (temporary) in workspace /home/ubuntu/workspace/container
[] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6494228973021674867.sh
Performing Post build task...
Match found for : : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Running script  : echo "running post build task"
[ifx-pre-jill] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins194585219316925654.sh
+ echo running post build task
running post build task
POST BUILD TASK : SUCCESS
END OF POST BUILD TASK : 0
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I can't see the logs for deployment. Am I missing something?

I tried referring this https://www.jdev.it/deploying-your-war-file-from-jenkins-to-tomcat/, but it does not give me option to enter manager username and password. So, I entered the ssh public key location for the tomcat instance as credentials.

Comment: I think this plugin doesn't support Tomcat 8.x yet.

Comment: I tried this even for Tomcat 7, but I can't see the logs to know if it is being executed or not.

Comment: you can do this without using this plugin by using a shell script.

Comment: yes of course, are you aware of any other plugins though?

Comment: I am not aware of any other plugin that does this task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cURL` to deploy your WAR file to Tomcat.

```
curl -T "app.war" "http://managerUser:managerPass@http://<TOMCAT_URL>/manager/text/deploy?path=/appContext&update=true"
```

Comment: `curl -T "test.war" "http://tomcat:tomcat@192.168.248.190:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/test&update=true" -v`

```
*   Trying 192.168.248.190...
* Connected to 192.168.248.190 (192.168.248.190) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'tomcat'
> PUT /manager/deploy?path=/test HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.248.190:8080
> Authorization: Basic dG9tY2==
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 374778991
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 0

```

Comment: So, can you open your tomcat manage page -`http://192.168.248.190:8080/manager/html`?

Comment: Hi, Can anyone advice on how to undeploy the older versions of the app using curl. For eg: if I upload "app-1.1.war" using curl then it should delete "app-1.0.war" Note: there are two places we need to clear "/webapps" & "/work". I tried curl -i -X DELETE 'http://myserver:8080/manager/text/deploy?update=true&path=/webapps/app-1.0.war' 

I am not confident if the URL with deploy? is the right one to use. Any advice please?